# ASP.NET API in Docker container

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have a fresh webapi project that was just created with the dotnet tool, and it is running in a Docker container that was created with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY net-auth.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
CMD ["dotnet", "watch", "run"]
```

I pass the code in through a volume with this compose file:

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile.dev.yml
      tags:
        - "jk/netauth:latest"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/src
```

When the container is started I lost IntelliSense and VSCode complains:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): Error: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers, version 6.0.9 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions.

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /Users/user/repos/net-auth/net-auth.csproj
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that making my own image is not required and removed the dev dockerfile for my API, I'm standing up a basic container with the dotnet sdk through Docker compose like this:

```
api:
    container_name: netauth
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    working_dir: /src
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - E__API__DB__HOST=edb_dev
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/src
    command: dotnet watch run --project net-auth.csproj
```

And it seems to work fine now, so problem solved either way.